# Map Exported from GEE to QGIS shows wrong class symbology

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, export

I performed an Unsupervised classification in GEE with 3 classes and exported the result to QGIS using:

```
Export.image.toDrive({ 
  image: result_Unsupervised, 
  folder: 'Brazil', 
  description:'SaoPaolo_Unsupervised_Classification', 
  region: ForestPlantation_Boundry,
  scale:10,
  maxPixels:1e13,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'.
```

The map in GEE is shown perfectly with 3 colors,

[image]

however, when I open it in QGIS, I see this map:

[image]

The problems are that:

1: it did not get exported in the boundry of the region that I specified while exporting (which is the black square on the map)

2: the 3 classes are shown with green, blue, red colors and if I use Paletted/Unique values in the properties and classify it, the green color is not showing the classified class and is extended over all the map for no reason. So if I delete the green class, I remain with only 2 classes. SOmehow my third class is mixed with the background.
Since in GEE, the map is showing perfectly as below, what am I doing wrong in QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your masked pixels will be `0` in your exported GeoTIFF. If you want to keep your green class as `0`, you can pick a different value for your masked pixels with `unmask()`.

```
image: result_Unsupervised.unmask(-1)
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Wiell. This line solved the problem and I accept this answer. For me to understand the process better, I will appreciate it you can explain a bit about why the masked pixels get exported as 0? I am not using any mask function here.